# Why this AVX code so slow?

Tags: c++, performance, sse, simd, avx

Well, the code is, and question is why AVX version is more slower than naive variant ?

```
const double __declspec(align(16)) mx[4] = { 1., 1., 1., -100.};
const double __declspec(align(16)) an[8] = { 8., 7., 6., 5., 4., 3., 2., 1.};

__forceinline double x_1(const double a, const double b, const double c, const double e)
{
    if(a < e)
    {
        if (b < a)
        {
            if (c < b)
            {
                return a + e;
            }
            else
            {
                return b + e;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (c < b)
            {
                return c + e;
            }
            else
            {
                return a + e;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (b < a)
        {
            if (c < b)
            {
                return b + e;
            }
            else
            {
                return c + e;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (c < b)
            {
                return a + e;
            }
            else
            {
                return b + e;
            }
        }
    }
}

union un {
    double __declspec(align(16)) m[4] = { 0., 1., 2., 3. };
    __m256d x;
};

un v;

__forceinline double x_2()
{
    _mm256_zeroupper();
    return an[_mm256_movemask_pd(_mm256_cmp_pd(v.x, _mm256_load_pd(mx), _CMP_LT_OS))];
}

int main()
{
    {
        double a = 0.;
        double b = 1.;
        double c = 2.;

        double r = 0.;

        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 30); ++i)
        {
            r = x_1(a, b, c, 1.);
            std::swap(a, b);
            std::swap(b, c);
        }
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "NAIVE " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " : " << r << "\n";
    }

    {
        double r = 0.;
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 30)  ++i)
        {
            r = x_2();
            std::swap(v.m[0], v.m[1]);
            std::swap(v.m[1], v.m[2]);
        }
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "AVX : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " : " << r;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it on MSVC with Full Optimize, and /arch AVX, but even simply calling _mm256_vzeroupper is slower than x_1 func... Why ? And when i need to use 'compare intrinsics', so that it was faster than native code ?

**My timing for x_1() - 2,5 sec, for x_2() - 11.7 sec**

Comment: Are you sure the branch predictor can't see through your swap trick?

Comment: I'm not sure, actually that's the whole question :) I want to know, when using SIMD AVX CMP will be faster. The code above - is my simple test case, but in practice i would like to use it in a real function, when the input parameters is calculating in process. But, this simple test case distresses me :(

Comment: Your function `x_1` doesn't have any side-effects and the result is only used at the last iteration, so the compiler should be smart enough to call it only once (and it might be smart enough to figure out what happens to `a,b,c` after `1<<30` iterations without going through the loop). Make sure that `x_1` is not inlined, to measure its performance. Also, you should call `_mm256_zeroupper();` only when switching from AVX code to SSE code, not randomly inside AVX code (I don't know what the actual impact of that is, but it can't be beneficial ...)

Comment: @chtz I think if the compiler used only the last iteration, then this function(x_1) was not performed for 2 seconds. Also intel in official blog recommended always use zeroupper in avx functions. Well, maybe naive variant really faster :?

Comment: Include the actual times in your question.  Since you forced them to inline and called them with compile-time constants, anything other than optimizing away entirely is a missed optimization by the compiler, for both.  (Oh actually, the AVX version loads its data from a global, not a `static`, so the compiler doesn't know that library functions don't modify it.)

Comment: @chtz: gcc/clang/MSVC insert a `vzeroupper` for you at the end of any function that uses 256b operations but doesn't return a 256b vector. (Unless you compile with `gcc -mno-vzeroupper`, I think, then you could manually control it.) https://godbolt.org/g/sfea1e  **You typically don't need to manually `_mm256_zeroupper()`**, but it may not hurt (except with clang).  I didn't look at what happens when inlining into a loop.  It's 4 uops on Intel (1 per clock throughput), no execution ports.  It's quite slow on Ryzen: 17 uops, one per 6 clocks (in 64-bit mode).  http://agner.org/optimize/

Comment: MSVC doesn't particularly optimize either loop at all, but the AVX one is very bad (store/reload to memory). https://godbolt.org/g/HxXsfD (see `$LL4@main:` and `$LL7@main:` for the loops.)  It does sink the `vzeroupper` out of the loop for you, so IDK what you did to find that `x_1()` was slower than `_mm256_vzeroupper()`.

Comment: i mean, that vzeroupper slower than x_1 when it's execute in every iteraion of the loop :)(MSVC 2015 x64)

Comment: Well, how about speedup x_2 function ?

Comment: What hardware?  i7-6700k (Skylake)?  Or Piledriver? Or Ryzen?  Include your CPU model number if you don't know the name of the microarchitecture.  Also, how do you know that MSVC actually put `vzeroupper` inside the loop?  Did you check the asm output?  Or did you just assume based on putting `_mm256_vzeroupper()` inside your C++ loop?

Comment: My hardware is: intel i7 4750HQ(2hhz).
And here is ASM code(https://sun9-2.userapi.com/c639920/v639920245/43453/plCE-lDTZcY.jpg), well - and as i understand compiler not use vzeroupper ? Well, but x_2 slower than x_1. For x_1 compiler generate full code, as i can see.(i comment in x_2 function comparision intrinsics, but left only vzeroupper and return 1.)

Comment: Ok, that's a Haswell.  What happens if you take out the `_mm256_vzeroupper()`.  MSVC is probably doing such a terrible job because it's still spilling the `ymm` vector because of the `vzeroupper`, even though it ended up optimizing `vzeroupper` out of the loop.

Comment: When it's out, programm works fast:
https://sun9-11.userapi.com/c639920/v639920245/43467/D2lQqMiqMGk.jpg
And it's asm:
https://sun9-11.userapi.com/c639920/v639920245/43475/SeAAl_Ozai0.jpg

Comment: i can't unerstand, why if even vzeroupper is after the loop, programm works slower:
https://sun9-11.userapi.com/c639920/v639920245/434ac/h1vn52ixhd0.jpg

Comment: std::swap(v.m[0], v.m[1]);
   std::swap(v.m[1], v.m[2]);
It's problematic strings of the code, but how without them - i can't understand. 
?